# Is there way to find all CSS code used by my HTML code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to find all Bootstrap CSS code that the following HTML code uses. What tool(s) or method(s) can I use to do this? I prefer text/code editors. I don't want to search by hand. It takes too much time.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
      aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><b>Test</b></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/create"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Geography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mathematics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Religion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Society</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {{#if user}}
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class="img-circle" src="/images/profile_photo.jpg" width="20" height="20"> {{username}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/profile">My Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="/settings">My Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      {{else}}
      <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" href="/login">Log In</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
      {{/if}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: strike F12 & "This is a line of text in order to meet the minimum words requirement of Stack Overflow :)"

Comment: @GCyrillus Is there a way to do this in editors?

Comment: in editors you'll have to search  for the class  name then unless some plugins exists for your editor :)

Comment: @GCyrillus It takes too much time to inspect each element in Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to idleberg's answer.
Instead of having to do it programmatically, you can use this firefox plugin to scan for (un)used css code: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss). It scans static HTML pages for used elements and classes and compiles a reduced CSS file. It can be integrated in your [Gulp](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) or [Grunt](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) tasks.